# FreeRTOS two CPU clocks

Tags: c, stm32, freertos

Dependent on a HW assembly variant my firmware should operate with 2.1 or 4.2 MHz. In FreeRTOS `configCPU_CLOCK_HZ` is already set while compile time. Is there any possibility to set this frequency while initialisation time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`configCPU_CLOCK_HZ` seems to be used in `vPortSetupTimerInterrupt()` function, which simply configures SysTick hardware registers (if you're not using *tickless mode*). I guess it should be possible to configure these register manually even when the scheduler is running (but I'm not sure).

But there is probably a better way: `vPortSetupTimerInterrupt()` is defined with `__attribute__((weak))` in the source code. It means that, if you provide your own version of `vPortSetupTimerInterrupt()`, it will replace the original one. In your own version, simply load SysTick CTRL & LOAD registers with the appropriate values.

Here is the original version of `vPortSetupTimerInterrupt()` (This can vary depanding on the uC model):

```
/*
 * Setup the systick timer to generate the tick interrupts at the required
 * frequency.
 */
__attribute__( ( weak ) ) void vPortSetupTimerInterrupt( void )
{
    /* Calculate the constants required to configure the tick interrupt. */
    #if ( configUSE_TICKLESS_IDLE == 1 )
        {
            ulTimerCountsForOneTick = ( configSYSTICK_CLOCK_HZ / configTICK_RATE_HZ );
            xMaximumPossibleSuppressedTicks = portMAX_24_BIT_NUMBER / ulTimerCountsForOneTick;
            ulStoppedTimerCompensation = portMISSED_COUNTS_FACTOR / ( configCPU_CLOCK_HZ / configSYSTICK_CLOCK_HZ );
        }
    #endif /* configUSE_TICKLESS_IDLE */

    /* Stop and clear the SysTick. */
    portNVIC_SYSTICK_CTRL_REG = 0UL;
    portNVIC_SYSTICK_CURRENT_VALUE_REG = 0UL;

    /* Configure SysTick to interrupt at the requested rate. */
    portNVIC_SYSTICK_LOAD_REG = ( configSYSTICK_CLOCK_HZ / configTICK_RATE_HZ ) - 1UL;
    portNVIC_SYSTICK_CTRL_REG = ( portNVIC_SYSTICK_CLK_BIT | portNVIC_SYSTICK_INT_BIT | portNVIC_SYSTICK_ENABLE_BIT );
}
```

You can probably just copy the original one (without the *weak* attribute of course) and replace `configCPU_CLOCK_HZ` with some global variable you set in your code.